# Modulo in For Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration, modulo

I am learning C++. I need to iterate 10000 times in a `for` loop, and every 100 times (using `%`) there should be a dot "." printed NEXT TO the number. The main problem is, how to put the "." next to the number?

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
    cout << i << endl;
    if(i % 100 == 0) {
        cout << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so the main problem is how to put "." NEXT TO number ??

Just do `endl` only once:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
        cout << i;
        if(i % 100 == 0) {
            cout << ".";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```